# Confirm(jquery) antes de enviar formulario submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, confirmar

estoy tratando de agregar una confirmación antes de enviar el formulario, estoy usando la librería de jquery(jquery-confirm).

Me lo está enviando igual al formulario, por más q no presione en el aceptar del confirm.

```
                <form id="form_edit" method="post" action="<?php echo $urlGeneral; ?>php/edit.php" class="texto-12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id_a_editar" value="<?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-6">
                            <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nombre" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-6">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" required>
                        </div>
                     
                        <div class="col-6"></div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

codigo javascript:

```
$("#form_edit").submit(function () {
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Guardar',
    content: 'Gardar datos?',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            alert("GUARDADO");
        },
        cancel: function () {
            return false;
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Utiliza el método confirm de javascript. Por ejemplo:

if(confirm("mensaje que aparecerá en el confirm"){
   tu lógica de código
}

Comment: Por que tu `type="submit"` es el botón que dice *Cancelar*..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poner id al botón guardar y asignarle un evento:

```
$( "#guardarBtn" ).click(function() {
  
$.confirm({
    title: 'Guardar',
    content: 'Gardar datos?',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $( "#form_edit" ).submit();
        },
        cancel: function () {
            return false;
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        }
    }
  });
});
```